# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException when using giant recycleview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-transitions, parcel

I'm getting this annoying exception in my main activity sometimes.
the stack trace is like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tomatedigital.lottogram, PID: 4430
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 543588 bytes
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4156)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 543588 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:761)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:5147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4148)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

The trace itself is not very helpfull since it doesn't specify which component or what transaction Id or Tag is related to the Exception (google please think about the debuggability of the crap you put out there)...
but i do suspect it is the recycleview i have in my main activity.

This recycleview might get super loaded, THOUSANDS of items. each of them contains: 3 small strings, 1 large string and one small bitmap.

When this recyclerview is overloaded and the activity is suspended this exception is thrown. Since the recyclerview is created inflating the layout.xml, android do save its state automaticly.

Is there any easy way to workaround this problem?
Is possible to set the App to allow "super large Transaction"?
What can i do?

================UPDATE===================
to provide aditional information about my Activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        outState.putSerializable("media", this.media); //this is a domain class
        outState.putBoolean("canceled", this.canceled);
        outState.putInt("speed", this.speed);
        outState.putLong("startTime", this.startTime);
        outState.putSerializable("comments", (Serializable) this.adapter.getList()); //this is the large data
        outState.putBoolean("commentLoadComplet", this.complete);
        outState.putSerializable("fetched", (Serializable) this.fetched);
        outState.putSerializable("igiboAttendees", (Serializable) this.igiboAttendees);
        outState.putLong("winnerId", this.winnerId);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Comment: It is not very likely that the _RecyclerView_ is the culprit here, as the items all have the same ids (so only one copy of data is saved, if at all) and the parent only saves a small amount of information (like scroll position). However, it's quite possible that _you_ are saving the adapter's data set in `onSaveInstanceState()`. Are you?

Comment: @BenP., now that you mentioned i re-checked and i do save the adapter state. What is the android built-in easiest way to save that data instead of using the activity state?

Comment: Hey Rafael, I experience the exact same problem and I am 100% sure it is caused by the RecyclerView that grew too big. I don't save any data in the `onSaveInstance` method or anywhere else. I'm actively investigating this and will update you if I find out something.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically caused by saving large amounts of data in onSaveInstanceState, not only for the activity in which the exception occurred, but also in other activities currently in the back stack.

One solution is to use the ViewModel class to maintain state instead of onSaveInstanceState:

[ViewModel Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

You may still use onSaveInstanceState for small amounts of data, but keep in mind it adds up over all the activities.